# Aligning the thumbnail image

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails

I want to control the alignment of the featured image(the thumbnail) with the options given in the 'Set featured image' pop box.

```
<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
   echo '<div class="border">'; the_post_thumbnail(); echo '</div>';
} ?>
```

I want to add to the div with the class of border a class floatleft or floatright(or nothing) according for what the user chooses.

Thanks!

Comment: Why add the unnecessary div? The img is a block. It has classes. Style the border around it directly.

Comment: because its a double border, you can see here: http://fanboy.co.il/works/debundle/

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($id, 'thumbnail', array('class' => 'alignleft')); ?>
```

see **[codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail)** for more

Comment: i need to add the alignleft call to div with the border class. and the align needs to be a var.